# How can I make a "really zero-height" box?

Tags: spacing

In my document I need to show some labels in draft mode. But they should have zero height and depth (the purpose is not to affect on resulting text: all exept labels should be the same in both draft and release modes).
But if my label used to be before section title, latex don't omit leading `\vspace`. This is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\vspace{3cm}
Here we see that \verb'\vspace' omits.\pagebreak

\vbox to 0pt{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{some text}}
\vspace{3cm}
But here it presents!

\end{document}
```

Even trick with `\raisebox` didn't help me.

The only variant I see is to make `\newif` like `\ifomitvspace` and to say `\omitvspacetrue` in macro, that creates comment, then `\title` should make a check and don't do `\vspace` if `\ifomitvspace`. To turn off this I should do `\everypar{\omitvspacefalse}`. 
But I think, this is ugly.

**UPD**
Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to struggle within vertical spaces in `paracol` environment. As it redefines `\everypar`, answer of David Carlisle don't work. My guess to use some flag and redefine \@vspace also don't work (because it omits *all* spaces instead of only top). It is sad.

Comment: The macro  `\smash{}` sets its argument height and depth to zero.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes If you really believe that it's this simple, go ahead and answer the question.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, anyway, it won't remove `\vspace`

Comment: `\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,0){some text}\end{picture}`, though  this removes the width too. `\vspace` is removed as requested.

Comment: @AlexG Like Steven's suggestion that doesn't actually address the issue (the Title of the question is misleading) the code in the example makes a zero height box, but still affects the position of following text.

Comment: I believe the problem is that producing a box switches TeX to horizontal mode. The box takes up no space, but `\section` (and everything else) will spit out vertical space to get to the next "paragraph".

Comment: @alexis no the main problem is that discardable items are discarded at the top of a page but by placing a box there even zero sized the skip is not at the top of the page and not discarded,  using picture mode (unlike the example in the question) does have the additional disadvantage of starting h mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tricky in general, you could look how color or showkeys packages try to avoid affecting position of the original text (without total success).

The `expl3` `l3galley` code tackles this by taking full control of vertical mode, which works if everything obeys the rules, but in latex2e with unconstrained access to latex and tex primitives adding to the vertical list that isn't really an option.

I would delay any vertical mode use until the next paragraph starts, where things are easier to control:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\let\oldeverypar\everypar
\oldeverypar{\the\everypar\the\mynotes\global\mynotes{}}
\newtoks\mynotes
\protected\long\def\mynote#1{%
\ifvmode
\global\mynotes\expandafter{\the\mynotes\smash{\raise\baselineskip\rlap{#1}}}%
\else
\smash{\raise\baselineskip\rlap{#1}}%
\fi}

\newtoks\everypar
\begin{document}
\vspace{3cm}
Here we see that \verb'\vspace' omits.\pagebreak

\mynote{some text}
\vspace{3cm}
But here it presents!

\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't a solution: you just put note after `\vspace`. Try to add after 'but here it presents' this: `\vspace{4cm}

\mynote{another note}
\vspace{4cm}
Text`. You will see, that second `\vspace` don't suppressed.

Comment: My mistake, subsequent `\vspaces` are summing, so your answer is right!

Comment: @Eddy_Em naturally:-)

Comment: But I think, I should make my own answer: your variant don't work with `paracol` enwironment.